# No value variation in returned column when using for loops and ifelse statements)

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement

I have written a function (`pre_post_comparision`) that takes a set of columns containing survey responses, and uses a `for` loop and a series of `ifelse` statements to conditionally increment a score on a variable called `bonus_points`.

The objective of the function is to return the `bonus_points` column containing a user's score. `bonus_points` should range between 0 and 3.

When running the function using the full dataset, the returned score has no variation, with a score of 2 for each user. When running the function one row at a same, I am able to achieve variation in the `bonus_points` variable (i.e. bonus_points range between 0, 1, 2, 3).

What changes should I make to the function so that I am returning the correct `bonus_points` score?

To help, below is an example of my code and dataset.

Thanks in advance!

**The pre_post_comparison function**

```
SEA_VALUE_LUT <- function(df){
  for (i in 1:length(df)){
    df[,i][df[i] == 4] <- 5
    df[,i][df[i] == 3] <- 4
    df[,i][df[i] == 2] <- 3
    df[,i][df[i] == 0] <- 0
  }
  return(df)
}

pre_post_comparison <- function(df, cap){  
  df$bonus_points <- 0
  for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(df)-2, by = 2)){
    x <- as.data.frame(df[,i])
    y <- as.data.frame(df[,i+1])
    is_strength <- TRUE
    pairs_df <- cbind(x, y)
    pairs_df <- SEA_VALUE_LUT(pairs_df)
    colnames(pairs_df) <- c("cur_value", "pre_value")
    attach(pairs_df)
    ifelse(cur_value >=3, 
           ifelse(is_strength && pre_value == 5,
                  df$bonus_points <- df$bonus_points + 1,
                  ifelse(!is_strength && pre_value == 0, 
                         df$bonus_points <- df$bonus_points + 1,
                         ifelse(pre_value == 2 || pre_value == 3 || pre_value == 4, 
                                df$bonus_points <- df$bonus_points + 1, NA))), NA)
    detach(pairs_df)
  }

  df$bonus_points[df$bonus_points > cap] <- cap
  return(df$bonus_points)
}
```

**Example data frame**

```
dput(Example.df)
structure(list(H.Response2.Attack = c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), H.Response.Attack = c(4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L), H.Response2.Budget = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), H.Response.Budget = c(4L, 
2L, 2L, 4L), H.Response2.Cred = c(4L, 3L, 3L, 4L), H.Response.Cred = c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

**Updated pre_post_comparison function based on QuickReaction's feedback**

```
pre_post_comparison <- function(sea_df, cap){  
  sea_df$bonus_points <- 0
  for(i in seq(from=1, to=length(sea_df)-2, by = 2)){
    x <- as.data.frame(sea_df[,i])
    y <- as.data.frame(sea_df[,i+1])
    is_strength <- TRUE # For now just assume 
    pairs_df <- cbind(x, y)
    pairs_df <- SEA_VALUE_LUT(pairs_df)
    colnames(pairs_df) <- c("cur_value", "pre_value")
    attach(pairs_df)
    boolean <- cur_value >=3 & ((is_strength & pre_value == 5)  | (!is_strength & pre_value == 0) | (pre_value == 2 | pre_value == 3 | pre_value == 4))
    sea_df[boolean,"bonus_points"] <- sea_df[boolean,"bonus_points"]+1
    detach(pairs_df)
  }
  print(sea_df$bonus_points)
  sea_df$bonus_points[sea_df$bonus_points > cap] <- cap
  return(sea_df$bonus_points)
}
```

Comment: Use `dput()` to provide your data, not a table. You do not understand the difference in R between `ifelse()` and `if() else()`. Do not use `ifelse()` inside a loop since it is vectorized. For example, `df <- sapply(sea_df, function(x) ifelse(x == 0, x, x+1))` instead of the first function.

Comment: Thanks. Can you suggest what else I would use instead of the `ifelse( )`? Switching to an `if( )` and `else ()` throws the following error `the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`.

Comment: I think you've got a problem with `&&` use. `&&` doesn't vectorize. Nor does `||`. You should try combining all of those `ifelse()` clauses into one boolean: `cur_value >=3 & ((is_strength & pre_value == 5)  | (!is_strength & pre_value == 0) | (pre_value == 2 | pre_value == 3 | pre_value == 4))`. Also, you can put that boolean in the row index... `pairs_df[boolean,"bonus_points"] <- pairs_df[boolean,"bonus_points"]+1`. That's how to better use R in its more "vectorized" form.

Comment: @quickreaction Thanks! This solved it perfectly. I've added the solution to code above. I really appreciate your help!